# Wordpress Single.php advanced custom fields loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a few advanced custom fields pages, they all have the same structure using a repeater field. I want them all to share the same single.php file. (which i believe should be fine?)

All my php is in the right order as its working fine when i add this above if have posts:

```
    <?php
    // The Query
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'chemicals'
      );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
```

But once it is removed it is not getting the post information.. Maybe I have my php structure wrong? im very new to php and wordpress so any help would be great.

```
    <div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_3_of_12">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(
    array(
    'menu'            => 'consumables',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'product-menu',
    'menu_class'      => 'product-menu',
    )); ?>
    </div>


        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php if( have_rows('product') ): ?>

                    <div class="col span_3_of_12">

                        <?php while( have_rows('product') ): the_row(); 
                            // vars
                            $title = get_sub_field('product_title');
                            $thumbnail = get_sub_field('thumbnail');
                            $blurb = get_sub_field('main_blurb');
                            $technical = get_sub_field('technical');
                            $description = get_sub_field('description');
                            ?>

                            <a href""><img class="open-image" src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>"></a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col span_6_of_12">

                            <div class="product-details">
                                <h4><?php echo $title; ?></h4>
                                <p><?php echo $blurb; ?></p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="product-tech">

                                <div class="technical">
                                    <h5>Technical</h5>
                                    <p><?php echo $technical; ?></p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="technical">
                                    <h5>Description</h5>
                                    <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    </div>

                <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: single.php is a post template and I think it's right. You have to put the acf fields (I see its a repeater field) inside each post.

Comment: Couple of things I've noted: 1) try changing if ( have_posts() ) : to if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : and 2) You should probably have a call to wp_reset_postdata() at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I see that yours is a custom post. The file name of the template should be single-chemicals.php instead of single.php

From WordPress codex:

> **single-{post_type}.php**  If your custom post type were 'product', and/or query_var = "product", WordPress would look for
>   single-product.php to display the single or permalink of the post.

Comment: Note: single.php will still work. See the template heirarchy here: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png . It all depends on the scenario really.

Comment: Hi JokiRuiz, I have done this already and it just pulls in every post rather than singling out the post that was clicked.

Comment: I dont think I should have to have multipul single.php files for what will be pushing the same fields?